# ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed when loading .pkl file

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pickle, joblib

Although there are many question threads for error `ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed`
I  couldn't find the answer for my problem

After training Machine learning model using SGDclassifer

```
clf=linear_model.SGDClassifier(loss='log',random_state=20000,verbose=1,class_weight='balanced')
model=clf.fit(X,Y)
```

Dimension of X is (1651880,246177)

The below code is working i.e when saving model object and when using model for prediction

`joblib.dump(model, 'trainedmodel.pkl',compress=3)`

`prediction_result=model.predict(x_test)`

but getting error when loading the saved model

`model = joblib.load('trainedmodel.pkl')`

below is the error message
Please help me out to resolve it.

```
  File "C:\Users\Taxonomy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 598, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)

  File "C:\Users\Taxonomy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 526, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()

  File "C:\Users\Taxonomy\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1050, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)

  File "C:\Users\Taxonomy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 352, in load_build
    self.stack.append(array_wrapper.read(self))

  File "C:\Users\Taxonomy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 195, in read
    array = self.read_array(unpickler)

  File "C:\Users\Taxonomy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 141, in read_array
    array = unpickler.np.empty(count, dtype=self.dtype)

ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

Comment: What happens if you reduce the size of your training data? (1651880,246177) seems large, idk if that can cause issues?

Comment: already i have reduced from 5300000 to 1651880 i can't reduce it further. My Server RAM size is 128GB. i think that should handle the size

Comment: I think that you are hitting an int overflow when using compression.May be It's a zlib issue. Could you try without compression? (i can imagine the huge size of pickled file). Try to upgrade sklearn to latest version, may be the issue was solved.

Comment: @amine Even for without compression I am getting same error. also i checked with upgrading sckit-learn to 0.21.3. couldnt solve issue

Comment: i  have thought that is this beacause of  highly sparsed matrix. <1651880x246177 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
 with 10842461 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

Answer (score 0):

Try to dump model with protocol 4.

from python's pickle [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html):

> Protocol version 4 was added in Python 3.4. It adds support for very
>   large objects, pickling more kinds of objects, and some data format
>   optimizations. Refer to PEP 3154 for information about improvements
>   brought by protocol 4.